# How does Python interpret a half 'empty' tuple (x,)?

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

I came across this code fragment and can't understand what is happening here.

```
X = np.linspace(-5,5,50)

Y = np.linspace(-5,5,50)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)

pos = np.empty(X.shape+(2,))
```

Why is `(2,)` necessary here and how does Python interpret half empty tuples like that in general?

Comment: That's how you write a tuple with one element.

Comment: The point is that (2) == 2 i.e., (2) is not a tuple. Thus a tuple with only one element needs a "special" syntax namely (2,)

Comment: _half empty tuple_ is interesting term. What would be _full tuple_?

Comment: So is that the same as (2, None)?

A full tuple to me is one where each component is determined. Is this part of pythons lazy evaluation or something?

Comment: `(2, None)` is a tuple with two elements, `2` and `None`. `(2,)` is a tuple with one element. Note that the parentheses are needed in your expression but in an assignment you could write e.g. `a = 2,`

Comment: ``(2,)`` is no more a "half empty tuple" than ``(2, 3,)`` is a "one third empty triple".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I was just confused how python deals with this.
It seemed to me like e.g. a function that lacks an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(2,)` is literal for tuple with one element. You need that in

```
pos = np.empty(X.shape+(2,))
```

as `X.shape` is `tuple` and `+` denotes concatenating tuples in `python`, in this particular example you are adding another dimension before using `numpy.empty`.

[Tuples and Sequence docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) put it following way

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1
> items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty
> tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with
> one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not
> sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses). Ugly, but
> effective.

Comment: So the resulting matrix is 50x50x2?
I.e. if one used ```pos = np.empty(X.shape+(50,))```
one would get a cubic matrix of 50x50x50?

Comment: @lpnorm yes, you will get 50x50x2 array with given code and 50x50x50 if you replace `(2,)` using `(50,)`

Answer (score 1):

According to the python language reference [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> A tuple of one item (a ‘singleton’) can be formed by affixing a comma to an
> expression (an expression by itself does not create a tuple, since
> parentheses must be usable for grouping of expressions).

Since `(2)` is an integer, you need to somehow inform the interpreter that what you mean is actually a tuple with a single item and you do that by adding the comma at the end.

you can test this by running this on the interpreter:

```
>>> type((2))
<class 'int'>
>>> type((2,))
<class 'tuple'>
```